# If condition TRUE in a row (that is grouped)

Tags: sql

Table:

```
|Months |ID|Commission|
|2020-01|1 |2312      |
|2020-02|2 |24412     |
|2020-02|1 |123       |
|...    |..|...       |
```

What I need:

```
COUNT(Months),
ID,
SUM(Commission),
Country

GROUP BY ID...
```

How it should look:

```
|Months |ID|Commission|
|4      |1 |5356      |
|6      |2 |5436      |
|...    |..|...       |
```

So I want to know how many months each ID received his commission, however (and **that's the part where I ask for your help**) if the ID is still receiving commission up to this month (current month) - I want to exclude him from the list. If he stopped receiving comm last month or last year, I want to see him in the table.
In other words, I want a table with old clients (who doesn't receive commission anymore)

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation.  Assuming there is one row per month:

```
select id, count(*)
from t
group by id
having max(months) < date_format(now(), '%Y-%m');
```

Note this uses MySQL syntax, which was one of the original tags.